# How to copy all the data from main server database to the local sqlite database to use locally?

Tags: python, django

**Local database setting-**

```
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
 }`
```

**main database setting-**

```
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '******',
        'USER': '******',
        'PASSWORD': '********',
        'HOST': '******', 
       'PORT': '****',
    }
}`
```

I did it from the git project 
`python manage.py dumpdata > all.json` . But then I don't know what to do next like how to use this json file to **update** local database by which commands.

I am very beginner to this. kindly help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python manage.py migrate    
python manage.py loaddata all.json
```

this command will load entire data to database whatever you specified in settings.py

Comment: Its shows some error - `raise  ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb`

Comment: That's nothing to do with this answer. If you have mysql and python configured properly (according to your question you do). This error would not arise. Please post another question for that. (or search the archives, it's been asekd and answered)

Answer (score 2):

You should always use an RDBMS from the same vendor at both ends. And preferably the same version. Though ORMs such as Django's are supposed to be database agnostic, there are still many subtle differences between different vendor's products. Sqlite for example is the least feature complete of the popular open source databases. If you use sqlite in development, and postgresql in production, you are limiting yourself to the set of features that sqlite has. But postgresql has many more. Right end of sermon.

At the live server do

```
python manage.py dumpdata > data.json
```

Then copy the file over to the local machine and do:

```
python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

Comment: Problem with me was to get the file from remote server to my local directory which is solved by [Transferring Files Securely with SCP and SFTP - Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJZbEt8KgBU). and then done by this code. Thank u so much

Comment: glad to have been of help